# SQL QUERY replace NULL value in a row with a another value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, null

Here is an example of what I have:

---

```
CREATE TABLE test1(Account varchar(50), FiscalPeriod int, OpenBalance decimal(18,3),debitamt decimal(18,3), company varchar(10), SegValue1 int);

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1155-000-', 0,1000000,0,'EII',1155);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1155-000-', 1,0,45000,'EII',1155);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1155-000-', 2,0,250,'EII',1155);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1155-000-', 3,0,60000,'EII',1155);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1156-000-', 0,55000,0,'EII',1156);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1156-000-', 1,0,850,'EII',1156);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(NULL, 2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1156-000-', 3,0,4000,'EII',1156);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1157-000-', 0,150000,0,'EII',1157);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(NULL, 1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1157-000-', 2,0,6000,'EII',1157);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1157-000-', 3,0,100,'EII',1157);

SELECT  * FROM  test1
```

---

The table above is an example of what my CTE looks like when querying a database.  In this base query I have added in the places where the FiscalPeriod is missing by using a month Control (date Control) table.  Doing this obviously creates the rows which have the nulls it them.

What I would like to do is replace the NULL's in the columns "Account", "Company", and "SegValue1" with the values from the row containing the FiscalPeriod equaling "0" per each Account.
As an example, the Account "10-1156-000-" was missing a row with the fiscal period of "2".  When the row was added using the monthControl table, all but the fiscalperiod column contained Nulls.  The columns "Account", "Company", and "SegValue1" should contain the sam value which are in the row with the fiscalperiod of "0" AND where the account is equal to "10-1156-000-".
In the account "10-1157-000-" it was missing the fiscalperiod "1".  The nulls in that row need to me filled with data from the row with the fiscalperiod of "0" AND the account is equal to "10-1157-000-".

There could be any number of Accounts which the query pulls and any number of these accounts could be missing a fiscalperiod or multiple fiscalperiods which need to be added and filled in.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is an example of my desired output for this given situation:

```
CREATE TABLE test1(Account varchar(50), FiscalPeriod int, OpenBalance decimal(18,3),debitamt decimal(18,3), company varchar(10), SegValue1 int);

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1155-000-', 0,1000000,0,'EII',1155);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1155-000-', 1,0,45000,'EII',1155);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1155-000-', 2,0,250,'EII',1155);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1155-000-', 3,0,60000,'EII',1155);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1156-000-', 0,55000,0,'EII',1156);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1156-000-', 1,0,850,'EII',1156);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1156-000-', 2,0,0,'EII',1156);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1156-000-', 3,0,4000,'EII',1156);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1157-000-', 0,150000,0,'EII',1157);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1157-000-', 1,0,0,'EII',1157);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1157-000-', 2,0,6000,'EII',1157);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('10-1157-000-', 3,0,100,'EII',1157);

SELECT  * FROM  test1
```

Comment: Can you add your desired output?

Comment: I added the desired output.

Comment: This would be a lot simpler with less data to look at.  Why not show just the rows with null data and the rows you want to get data from.

Comment: @Kevin . . . SQL tables have no inherent order.  You seem to want the information from the "previous" row.  Does your table have an auto-incrementing id or some other way to determine where the account comes from?

Comment: I do not want the information from the previous row. I want, where the fiscalperiod is missing from my table, to somehow add the missing fiscal period in (in the query only, not table) and do so with the account, company and segvalue1 columns filled in with values from the row where the fiscal period is "0" and where the account is missing a fiscal period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be best off deleting the NULL rows and then inserting the "missing" ones, like this:

```
delete test1 where Account is null;

with FiscalPeriods(n) as (
    select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
), newrows as (
    select Account,n,OpenBalance,debitamt,company,SegValue1
    from test1 t
    cross join FiscalPeriods f
    where t.FiscalPeriod=0 and not exists(select * from test1 x where x.Account=t.Account and x.FiscalPeriod=n)
)
insert test1
select * from newrows;
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want.  Thank you for thinking outside the box, as I see that I did not discribe what I wanted as good as I should have.  :)  I knew there was a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it for `Company` and `SegValue1`:

```
update t
    set Company = coalesce(t.Company, newvals.Company),
        SegValue1 = coalesce(t.SegValue1, newvals.SegValue1)
    from test1 t join
         (select *
          from test1
          where FiscalPeriod = 0
         ) newvals
         on t.account = newvals.account
    where t.Company is NULL or t.SegValue1 is NULL;
```

You can't use the same method for `Account`, because there is no way to match to the new values.

Comment: Thank you, but I need a way to do it for all three columns. Also, I gave example output for a query I have.  I can not update the tables with the information.

Comment: @Kevin . . . Your rule is, quote,  "What I would like to do is replace the NULL's in the columns "Account", "Company", and "SegValue1" with the values from the row containing the FiscalPeriod equaling "0" per each Account."  You cannot do this for `Account`.

Comment: When I ran the above solution, it did not even update the company and segvalue1 columns.  It states "0 row(s) affected"

Comment: @Kevin . . . That is because the account is also missing on those rows.  There is no "FiscalPeriod equaling "0" per each Account".

Comment: Ok, i understand what you are saying now and I'm sorry I did not be more specific.  I would like to create a row for each missing fiscalperiod for each account with the data filled in.